# Query com duas ordenanções em ordem decrescente

Tags: mysql, sql

Existe a possibilidade de executar uma *query* pesquisando pelo número do contrato, ordenando por data decrescente e suas respectivas ordens de serviço?
Se sim, podem me passar um exemplo para conhecimento??

Query utilizada:

```
SELECT * FROM field WHERE contrato LIKE '%$buscar%' ORDER BY Data,Num_OS DESC
```

Comment: Supostamente como você tem já faria isso. Onde está o problema?

Comment: acho q se vc colocar `data desc, num_os` resolveria... veja esse exemplo no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33b9a6/1)

Comment: Senhores, resolvido... thanks,.

Comment: qual solução? seria bom [além de se ajudar] ajudar outros

Comment: SELECT * FROM field WHERE contrato LIKE '%$buscar%' ORDER BY Data,Num_OS DESC ou SELECT * FROM field WHERE contrato LIKE '%$buscar%' ORDER BY Data DESC, Num_OS

Comment: Coloque uma resposta com a solução, evite colocá-la em comentário apenas.

Comment: como faço isso??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sim, é possível. Você só precisa colocar os campos que pretende ordenar no comando de ordenação do *mysql*: [**`order by`**](https://www.diegomacedo.com.br/como-ordenar-o-resultado-de-uma-consulta-no-mysql-order-by/):

```
SELECT * --campos que deseja retornar
FROM nome_tabela
WHERE num_contrato = @num_contrato --@num_contrato será o contrato a ser pesquisado
ORDER BY data, ordem_servico desc --desc é palavra reservada e indica que a ordenação é decrescente
```

É importante você dar uma olhada no *link* que coloquei e estudar um pouco sobre ordenação. Tem muito material bom na net, vale pesquisar!!

Comment: perdoe a ignorância prezado, como faria para que este resultado fosse exibido em linhas diferentes? ou seja em uma linha o numero do contrato e uma data e uma ordem de serviço, na outra linha o mesmo contrato e uma outra data e outra ordem de serviço??? pode me explicar melhor??

Comment: da forma que está acredito que já seja retornado desta maneira. você deve ter em uma linha algo do tipo _contrato 123, data 01/10/2018, os 1_ e na outra _contrato 123, data 01/10/2018, os 2_. Assim, já trará o resultado como espera. Faz o teste ;)

Comment: esta é a query: "SELECT * FROM field WHERE contrato LIKE '%$buscar%' ORDER BY Data,Num_OS DESC"

Comment: e qual o problema?

Comment: realmente de acordo com o que você escreveu eu fiz mas ele não me mostra, exibe apenas uma data e sua respectiva ordem de serviço e nas outras linhas não exibe as outras datas e as sus ordens de serviço.

Comment: como faço para enviar uma imagem da tabela??? acredito q ajudara melhor a entender..        segue abaixo  a estrutura da tabela:                           Login, Data, Ordem de Serviço, Tipo da Os, Agenda, Contrato

Comment: se só exibe um valor, então o seu número de contrato é único. De qualquer forma, clique em editar (na pergunta) e adicione mais informação, tipo estrutura da tabela, se retorna erro, dados (se for o caso)

Comment: como faço para enviar uma imagem da tabela??? acredito q ajudara melhor a entender.. segue abaixo a estrutura da tabela: Login, Data, Ordem de Serviço, Tipo da Os, Agenda, Contrato , quando pesquisa ele me diz que tem 5 registros deste contrato.